# How to map a raw tcp connection using Nginx and Node.js?

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have a simple TCP node server listening in localhost:9000 and I would like to map the incoming connections from a specified domain to this address.

The server works properly in local, but when I try to access to it from outside, **Nginx answer with a 400 bad request**.

The node server **IS NOT a HTTP server**, that means that the connection should be mapped in raw, Nginx doesn't should try to read the HTTP headers beaucese the request doesn't have it.

So I would like to have this server that is running locally, it will listen in a domain.

I have tried so many configurations of `/etc/nginx/sites-available/my-domain` but nothing works, Nginx always answer with **400 Bad Request**

I saw in the Nginx documentation than you can accept NON-HTTP request ([Link here](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/)) but when I tried it, it doesn't work.

I let some of that configurations that I have already tried:

With scgi ([Docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_scgi_module.html#scgi_bind)):
scgi_pass inside server:

```
server {
        listen 80 proxy_protocol;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /home/user/my-app;
        index server.js;

        server_name my-domain;
        proxy_protocol    on;
        scgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

}
```

scgi_pass inside location:

```
server {
        listen 80 proxy_protocol;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /home/user/my-app;
        index server.js;

        server_name my-domain;
        location / {
            include   scgi_params;
            scgi_pass localhost:9000;
        }

}
```

scgi_bind:

```
server {
        listen 80 proxy_protocol;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /home/user/my-app;
        index server.js;

        server_name my-domain;
        location / {
            include   scgi_params;
            scgi_bind localhost:9000 transparent;
        }

}
```

With fastcgi ([Docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html?_ga=2.231361439.1289649624.1626073914-1485398863.1625857064#fastcgi_pass)):

```
server {
        listen 80 proxy_protocol;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /home/user/my-app;
        index server.js;

        server_name my-domain;

       location / {
                # Mitigate https://httpoxy.org/ vulnerabilities
               fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";

               fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;

                # include the fastcgi_param setting
               include fastcgi_params;
        }

}
```

I also saw that to manage TCP connections, you can use `stream` ([Link here](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/using-proxy-protocol/#listen))

With stream:

```
 stream {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name my-domain;
        proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

}
```

I let here my Node.js script:

```
var net = require('net');
const HOST = '127.0.0.1', PORT = 9000;

// Server
const server = net.createServer();


server.on('connection', function (serverSocket) {
    console.log('Client connected to server at ' + serverSocket.remoteAddress + ':' + serverSocket.remotePort);
    serverSocket.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(`Data: ${data}`);

        // Do stuff

    });
    serverSocket.on('close', function () {
        
       // Do stuff

    });
    serverSocket.on('error', function (error) {
        throw error;
    })
});

server.listen(PORT, HOST, function () {
    console.log('Socket running at' + server.address().address + ':' + server.address().port);
});
```

Comment: If the request doesn't have HTTP headers, how do you expect Nginx to differentiate between requests to different domains? The IP packets will all have the same destination address. As far as I know, the only way Nginx (and other HTTP servers) tells them apart is using the `Host` HTTP header.

Comment: You are totally agree, so do you know how could I listen in a specific port of my public IP address? Maybe with: 
`
stream {
    server {
  listen 9000;
  listen [::]:9000;
        proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}
`
With this configuration could I map a public address:port to a local address:port ?

Answer (score 1):

I answer my question, so here is the solution that works for me.

The key is thats HTTP is over TCP and Nginx is a HTTP server. Fortunately, Nginx has a module ([ngx_stream_core_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_core_module.html)) to manage plain TCP request.

So, in the Nginx config `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, you need to add the outsite TCP IP:PORT that will be mapped inside (locally). To do that **you need to add the following code  before or after http block** where 4000 is where your local server is hearing locally and 5000 is the public port where your server will be listening and the port that you should to call from your external aplications.

```
stream {
    upstream tcp_connection{
        server 127.0.0.1:4000            max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    }
    server {
        listen 5000;
        proxy_pass tcp_connection;
    }
}
```

So, like that you will map you public IP and a public port (5000 in this case) to a internal IP (Localhost) and an internal port (4000) in this case.

Important! I must open the public port in your OS, you may use iptables or ufw.